# VSTS Build with Gulp-Generated Files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, gulp, azure-devops

I currently have a VSTS build that takes in a Visual Studio solution and builds it (C#) with the following build parameters:

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:UseMerge=true /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true  /p:SingleAssemblyName=AppCode"`

I also have various Gulp tasks that take in my front-end files and manipulate them (lint, minify, bundle, etc.) as part of this build. The problem is that the zip that is created from the solution build step doesn't include these distribution files (or any file that's not included in the solution.)

In general it's a bad idea to check in distribution files, you need to generate them as part of the production build. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to get these files to generate (the build is working for this step) -AND- get them included as part of the zip file generated as part of the solution build?

Comment: Can you share the project (as the web project with nodejs and gulp) you build in one drive? And what's your build definition?  And what do you mean "distribution files"?

Comment: Production files Gulp generates, i.e. distribution files. You would only deploy distribution, production-ready files to production, not development files. The definition has numerous steps to build and test everything before bundling in a zip file to eventually release to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

To include Gulp-Generated Files into web application package zip file, you can get the web application package files into another directory (such as `$(build.binariesdirectory)`) and after execute all the Gulp tasks, you can add the Gulp-Generated Files into `$(build.binariesdirectory)`. Then zip files from `$(build.binariesdirectory)` and publish the artifacts.

Detail settings as below:

1. In VS Build task, change MSBuild arrguments as:

   ```
   /p:OutDir="$(build.binariesdirectory)\\"
   ```
2. Add a task (PowerShell task or Copy Files task etc) to copy the Gulp-Generated Files to `$(build.binariesdirectory)`.
3. Add an Archive Files task to zip files from `$(build.binariesdirectory)` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` as below example:

   [image]

Now the zip file not only contains the package files of the web application, but also contains the Gulp-Generated Files.